# jQuery Mobile Navbar links not working when iframe is used on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, iframe

I have a mobile project that I have created using jQuery Mobile.

The problem I am experiencing only (appears to) happens on Android Devices.

My application consists of a fixed header (at the top) and fixed footer (at the bottom) and some content (between the header and footer).

The footer contains links (within a navbar) and the content contains an iFrame. I am pulling different pages into the iFrame (source) depending on the current page (selected from the navbar) etc...

The iframe is contained within a div and the height is set to 100% so that it fits the applications content area. Everything works as expected - when loading the app in my desktop browser (to test) and also on IOS devices etc... E.g. The iFrame loads and renders the iFrames source correctly and allows me to use the navbar in the footer to change between the pages (loading new content into the iframe each time).

However, on Android, the iFrame also loads and renders correctly, although I am not able use the navbar (I cant click the links). It appears that the content of the iFrame is being rendered off the page (outside the iFrame and containing div (although not visible) behind the footer / navbar (it is not cut or cropped) and I think it is taking touch event focus from the navbar itself (if that makes sense) - E.g. when I click / touch a link in the navbar, it is either ignored, or if (by chance) there is a link within the iframe rendered under the selected navbar link, the link from source within the iFrame is loaded and the navbar link is ignored...

I have been banging my head on this one for a while now, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Cheers !

Comment: Sounds like an issue with browser rendering the div columns. Have you tried a different browser? Perhaps it renders differently in that. You may need to look into CSS div positioning properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to a the latest version of jQuery mobile (updating my code accordingly) which seemed to fix this and other issues :) I would advise (and the lesson I learned is to) first updating to the latest libs if you experience any problems within this space.